# Python django change field attribute

Tags: python, django, model

i have field like this,

```
counter = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

and then after migrate i check my database

```
counter | int(11)
```

then i want change this field to be like,

```
counter = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

and after migrate when i check my database

```
counter | int(11)
```

not

```
counter | int(11),Unsigned,null
```

anyone can solve my problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works.

```
1. Delete the existing migration folder.
2. python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>
3. python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: thanks.. its worked form me.. but can you explains to me why what im done not working?

Comment: I guess your migrations folder still had the previous migration's data. So, deleting it and running makemigrations again worked.